# Why does my SQL stored procedure give an error when no result?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm trying to make a simple stored procedure where, if a certain parameter (pFirstPosition) is a certain value, I do a select with some others parameters as filter. The SELECT work only if there's at least a row. The problem is instead of returning null when there's no row, it returns an error. I am using MariaDB with phpMyAdmin and the error I have is

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> SQL query:
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said:
>
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Here's my stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
IF pFirstPosition = 'Top' THEN
   SELECT Leader,GameMode,Language.Name,MinRank,MaxRank from Lobby
   inner join Lobby_Position on Lobby.LobbyPositionId =
Lobby_Position.LobbyPositionId
   inner join Language on Lobby.LanguageId = Language.LanguageId
   WHERE Lobby.MinRank <= pUserRank
   AND Lobby.MaxRank >= pUserRank
   AND Language.Name = pLanguage
   AND GameMode = pGamemode;
End IF;
End
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't use `BEGIN` and `IF` in queries, they can only be used in stored procedures and triggers.

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1`

Comment: @Barmar sorry I said query but it is in a stored procedure. Like I said, it work except when its return nothing, which throw an error

Comment: @FrankerZ the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is already set to 1 (ON), I tried my stored procedure by putting it OFF but it doesn't really change anything

Comment: You can't set it to ON. 1 = ON, 0 = OFF

Comment: @FrankerZ then maybe it's phpmyadmin that show ON and OFF instead of 1 and 0. I did use 1 and 0 to change it but like I said, either set on 1 or 0 it doesn't work

Comment: The stored procedure code you are showing does not try to execute a `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS ...` statement... so you have an error that does not correspond to the code you are showing.  This discrepancy needs to be clarified, since the error reported has no obvious connection to this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly it was a phpmyadmin [bug that got fixed recently](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14614)

Answer (score 0):

"LANGUAGE" is a reserved word, so quote it with backtics:

```
   inner join `Language` on Lobby.LanguageId = Language.LanguageId
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't change anything, and I found out that it still work when I call it in PHP, so I think it's a phpmyadmin problem

Comment: File a bug report with phpmyadmin.